# google Analytics V4 cannot be imported?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics

I'am trying to add `Google Analytics` to my application

I've followed every step at this page

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#tracking-methods

the issue is `Eclipse` not recognized `Tracker` and `GoogleAnalytics`

the `Google play service` and every thing are installed from `SDK`

I've tried to search for `V4 Analytics SDK` i could't find it

i don't know if i mess something here

any advice ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the solution ..

`Google Analytics V4` has no SDK , its depends on `Google Play Services SDK`

So here is what i did :

1. download `Google Play Services SDK` from Android SDK
2. go to Android SDK folder on you PC partition
3. Follow this path `(/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/ )`
4. you'll find this folder ( `google-play-services_lib` ) <- thats what we need
5. now go to Eclipse and import this Project ( `google-play-services_lib` ) as Library
6. right click on your project Properties -> Android -> Second Tab ( Library ) Click `Add` and select `google-play-services_lib`

Now you've done you can use `Google Analytics V4` with no problems at all

**The Idea is you need to download and import `Google Play Services` to Eclipse then add the library to your project .**

enjoy coding ..

Comment: thanks, also I found it. Is it https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you need to add the google play services as dependency to gradle. For example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

After that click the Sync Project with Gradle Files icon and it should work.

Comment: I did this but doesn't work. Can't find the class EasyTracker